# "echo $PATH" shows the required path but "which" doesnt. What went wrong

Tags: path

I am on my way to manually install [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path). The echo shows the required path, but on running "which flutter", it doesn't.
Any guidance please?

Update: Command and its result:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/myusername/Instloc/flutter/bin

which flutter
```

gives no result

Steps I had done:

1. Downloaded the flutter's tar.xz file
2. Extracted to(using default archive manager Ubuntu[Note: Don't if that's applicable here - I had installed winrar for opening some rar4 files(Any problem after extraction?)]) to the location.
3. Since I prefer permanent flutter access, I skipping the third step in the actual link I followed the "Update your path" steps: I added the following lines in the  /home/.bashrc file

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/home/myusername/InstLoc/flutter/bin"
   ```

Result of

```
ls -Alh /home/myusername/InstLoc/flutter/bin
total 24K
drwxrwxr-x 7 myusername myusername 4.0K May  1 00:11 cache
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myusername myusername 2.1K May  1 00:09 dart
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername 1.4K May  1 00:09 dart.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myusername myusername 2.1K May  1 00:09 flutter
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername 2.5K May  1 00:09 flutter.bat
drwxrwxr-x 2 myusername myusername 4.0K May  1 00:09 internal
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of both commands

Comment: What's output of `ls -Alh /home/instloc/flutter/bin`?

Comment: Maybe you need to make it executable: `chmod +x /home/instloc/flutter/bin/flutter` ?

Comment: @muru, it's in the instloc(inside home)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, funny, it's showing"ls: cannot access '/home/instloc/flutter/bin': No such file or directory
" . even sudo

Comment: @pLumo, Its already executable.

Comment: @SomOneElse: so how are going to access it if the directory doesn't exist?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, ofcourse it does exist, it has files: flutter, dart etc. and some folders.

Comment: @SomOneElse: but you aren't looking for *flutter, dart etc. and some folders.* but for /home/instloc/flutter/bin which does not exist.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: sorry my bad(& thanks!) the "Home"was confusing(and ofcourse case sensitiveness); Now the ls works; it shows "total 24k" and lists the files and folders. But still "which flutter" not working. Anything more I might have missed?

Comment: Just to make sure: Your real `export PATH=...` and the `echo` output do have your actual username instead of `<username>`, right?

Comment: @DonHolgo, yes. It does have the original username.

Comment: @SomOneElse: Edit your original question to show output of commands we ask you to show. Many here will have no desire to help you if we have to wade through all the comments to see it. What is the output of `ls -Al /home/<username>/Instloc/flutter/bin` (Specifically, previous comments omitted the <username> portion... But to Un\*x, it is significant and will not show expected results without that.)

Comment: Is there any more things to be done for an executable, in general, to work? Or any special cases I should be aware of? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong with the updating of the .bashrc file. When I checked today the path showed old(incorrect) value. Meanwhile I had also verified the procedure by creating a dummy executable and adding its path to the $PATH, and "which dummyexec" and also the command "dummyexec" worked!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to self-answer your question!